# Extract generic type and return tuple generic type

Tags: typescript

I have this function which takes `Promise<T>` and currently returns `Promise<(null | any)[] | (any | null)[]>`,
and I wanted it to return `Promise<[Error, T]>`

```js
                                          //↓Here I want to pass the extracted type
const customAsyncAwait = <T extends Promise<any>>(promise: T) => {

  return (promise)
    .then(res => [null, res])
    .catch(error => [error, null]);

}
```

I use it like this,

```js
async function init() {

  const api = axios.get<Plants[]>('<API_NAME>'); //typeof api =  Promise<AxiosResponse<Plants[], any>>
  const [error, data] = await customAsyncAwait(api); //Currently, typeof data = any but I want it to be AxiosResponse<Plants[], any>

}
```

#### Update

I managed to get it work, but looks ugly, is there a better way?

```js
const customAsyncAwait = <T>(promise: Promise<T>): Promise<[Error, T]> => {
  const result: [Error, T] = [null, null];

  return promise
    .then((res) => {
      result[0] = null;
      result[1] = res;
      return result;
    })
    .catch((error: Error) => {
      result[0] = error;
      result[1] = null;
      return result;
    });
}
```

Comment: Let me know if [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXQK1N) works for you

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine That didn't work, but helped me to get desired result with ugly syntax, see the updated answer

Comment: It is better overload your function. See [here](https://tsplay.dev/WGVP9m)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution from this package [await-to-js](https://github.com/scopsy/await-to-js/blob/master/src/await-to-js.ts)

```js
const customAsyncAwait = <T>(promise: Promise<T>): Promise<[Error, T]> => {
  return promise
    .then<[null, T]>((res: T) => {
      return [null, res];
    })
    .catch<[Error, null]>((error: Error) => {
      return [error, null];
    });
};
```